# Vector norm identity

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Let $u$ and $v$ be orthogonal vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

**Questions:**

1. Is following identity is true:

$\Vert u+v\Vert^2+\Vert u-v \Vert^2=2\Vert u \Vert^2+2\Vert v\Vert^2$

Why/why not?

2. Also, which is greatest, ||u+v|| or ||u-v||?

This will help me understand my textbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.

$||u + v||^2 + ||u - v||^2 = (u+v) \cdot (u+v) + (u-v) \cdot (u-v)$

$= ( u \cdot u + 2 u \cdot v + v \cdot v ) + ( u \cdot u - 2 u \cdot v + v \cdot v )$

$= 2 u \cdot u + 2 v \cdot v$
$= 2 || u ||^2 + 2 || v ||^2$

Nope it's wrong, but you're close.

$\ $

2. You can't say which one is greatest without specifying what $u$ and $v$ are.

I'll give you some examples. Take $u_{1} = (1,0)$ and $v_{1}=(1,1)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then we find that:

$|| u_{1} + v_{1} || = || (1,2) || = \sqrt{ 5 } $

$|| u_{1} - v_{1} || = || (0,-1) || = 1 $

Take $u_{2} = (1,0)$ and $v_{1}=(-1,-1)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then we find that:

$|| u_{1} + v_{1} || = || (0,-1) || = 1 $

$|| u_{1} - v_{1} || = || (2,1) || = \sqrt{5} $